# Can a via be placed in between the pads of a resistor?

Tags: pcb, altium, routing

Can I place a via in between the pads of a resistor as shown in the image?[image]

Comment: Check with whoever is making the boards, but probably yes.

Comment: https://www.tempoautomation.com/blog/via-in-pad-guidelines-choosing-the-best-routing-for-your-smds-tempo-automation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the boards are machine assembled and do not have plugged vias you must ensure there is some solder mask between pads and vias, otherwise solder paste can wick into the via, making for a poor joint on the pad.

Answer (score 1):

I place vias like this routinely without issues.  I recommend tenting the via to mitigate any solder flow issues.  It's always a good idea to run design rules past the intended CM, in any case.